# Finding percentages out of multiple in array and returning whole object by chance

Tags: javascript

I currently trying to make a lucky dip selector for prizes, I have an object that I would like to somehow transform into percentages which all depend on one another. I looked at other solutions online and have trouble doing so where I am looking inside an array and returning the whole object inside by chance

The max percentage in example will be 100%, and each qty would work out to the correct percentage that qty: 22 has the most likely chance of being picked and qty: 1 being the rarest and so on

```
        { tshirts: [
            { "tshirtName":"Green Shirt", "qty": 1, },
            { "tshirtName":"Blue Shirt", "qty": 2, },
            { "tshirtName":"Red Shirt", "qty": 7, },
            { "tshirtName":"Yellow Shirt", "qty": 22, },
        ]}
```

At the moment I made the mistake of just doing the following:

```
const randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * prizes.tshirts.length);
console.log('Your prize is ' + prizes.tshirts[randomChoice].tshirtName);
```

But this does not take into account the different percentages needed for each qty, it makes it all a 25% chance each

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are you picking just one shirt, or will multiple be chosen? If the latter, you may want to specify, as each pick would have to recalculate the odds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a random number between 1 and total quantity sum and get an element based on that.

```js
let prizes = {"tshirts":[{"tshirtName":"Green Shirt","qty":1},{"tshirtName":"Blue Shirt","qty":2},{"tshirtName":"Red Shirt","qty":7},{"tshirtName":"Yellow Shirt","qty":22}]};

// variable for total quantity sum
let total = 0;

// create an array to keep reference of maximum value of random num
let range = prizes.tshirts.reduce((arr, { qty }, i) => {
  arr[i] = (total += qty);
  return arr;
}, [])

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  // get a random number between 1 to total
  const randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * total) + 1;

  // get index based on the range array  values
  const index = range.findIndex(v => v >= randomChoice)

  console.log('Your prize is ' + prizes.tshirts[index].tshirtName, randomChoice);
}
```

Comment: At first I was confused with the output of console.log(range) as I was trying to understand what was going on but Its really neat that it picks a number from the range total without needing percentages. Thank you very cool

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array and store a particular tshirts name as often as it's quantity.
Let me illustrate by a simple example. Imagine you have an array of numbers that looks a little like this:

```
var arr=[1,1,1,2];
```

If you now pick a random element out of this array using:

```
var element=arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

there will be a high chance that the chosen element will be a 1 simply because there are 3 times as much 1s than 2s.
The same principle can be applied to your use case though we use the shirt names instead of numbers.

```js
 var prizes = {
   tshirts: [{
       "tshirtName": "Green Shirt",
       "qty": 1,
     },
     {
       "tshirtName": "Blue Shirt",
       "qty": 2,
     },
     {
       "tshirtName": "Red Shirt",
       "qty": 7,
     },
     {
       "tshirtName": "Yellow Shirt",
       "qty": 22,
     },
   ]
 };
 var tempArray = [];
 prizes.tshirts.forEach(shirt => {
   for (var a = 0; a < shirt.qty; a++) {
     tempArray.push(shirt.tshirtName)
   }
 });
 var element = tempArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tempArray.length)];
 console.log(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let prizes = {
  tshirts: [
    {'tshirtName': 'Green Shirt', 'qty': 1},
    {'tshirtName': 'Blue Shirt', 'qty': 2},
    {'tshirtName': 'Red Shirt', 'qty': 7},
    {'tshirtName': 'Yellow Shirt', 'qty': 22}
  ]
};

// total count of shirts
let count = prizes.tshirts.reduce((a, b) => a + b.qty, 0);

// Create an array containing each shirt instance qty times
let extendedArray = prizes.tshirts
  .map(shirt => new Array(shirt.qty).fill(shirt)) // [[shirt1, shirt1], [shirt2, shitr2]]
  .flat(); // [shirt1, shirt1, shirt2, shirt2]

console.log(getRandomShirt());

/**
 * Simple integer random function
 */
function random(max, min) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

/**
 * Call this for getting a shirt.
 * Note, that the returned shirt is still the same instance like in prizes.tshirts
 */
function getRandomShirt() {
  let randomValue = random(count, 0);
  return extendedArray[randomValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const prizes = { tshirts: [ 
        { "tshirtName":"Green Shirt", "qty": 1,}, 
        { "tshirtName":"Blue Shirt", "qty": 2, }, 
        { "tshirtName":"Red Shirt", "qty": 7, }, 
        { "tshirtName":"Yellow Shirt", "qty": 22, } 
        ]}; 
 
 let Data = []; 
 
 prizes.tshirts.map(tshirt => { 
          let i = 0; 
          while( i < tshirt.qty){
               Data.push(tshirt.tshirtName); i++; }; 
          }); 
let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()*Data.length);        
console.log(Data[randomChoice]);
```